# A regular, non-Hausdorff, non-normal space

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

I'm trying to understand the relationship between the different separation axioms:

- T2 (Hausdorff): two distinct points can be separated by open sets
- Regular: a closed set and a point not in it can be separated by open sets
- Normal: two disjoint closed sets can be separated by open sets

I know that T4 (normal + T2) implies regular, so if a space is not regular, it is either not Hausdorff or not normal. I can't find out if it's possible to have a space that is regular, but not Hausdorff and not normal.

Comment: regular + $T_0$ already implies $T_1$ and regular + $T_1$ implies $T_2$, so an example cannot be $T_0$ either. The usual go-to example of an an indiscrete space does not work (it's normal).

Comment: Another "restriction" : a regular and second countable space is normal, so that already rules out all finite spaces and many more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take your favourite regular non-normal space $X$, for example the [Sorgenfrey plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_plane), now consider the indiscrete space $Y=\{0,1\}$, finally $X\times Y$ is regular because product of regular spaces (you can see it [here](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Regularity_is_product-closed), despite he says that a regular space is also $T_1$, the same proof works perfectly without this hypotesis), it isn't Hausdorff because $Y$ is not. It isn't also non-normal because if $A,B\subset X$ are closed set that you cannot separate with open, also $A\times Y$ and $B\times Y$ will be closed set of $X\times Y$ that you cannot separate with open, because the nonempty open are of the form $A\times B$ where $A\subset X$ and necessarily $B=Y$.